# rake db:migrate bundle: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm using Heroku and cloud9.io for my app.

I get the Error:

> bash: bundle: command not found

When i try run the command:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Localy my app works fine without any error but i'm not able to migrate and i get the Application on herokuapp.com path.

Comment: It seems similar issue posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13296063/5076451).

Comment: This does not work for me..

Comment: run `git push origin master` then run again `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: i did this a few times...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be due to the version of Ruby you are running.

I had a similar issue before, I tried everything possible(installing bundler, etc.), but one thing that worked for me was to manually set the config using following command:

`heroku config:add GEM_PATH=vendor/bundle/1.8`

Please note that you should change `1.8` to the version of Ruby you are currently running.

Comment: @olivier Hmm that is strange. I tell you one good thing to do is to get in touch with customer support at Heroku. Go to your dashboard at Heroku and click the "Feedback" button at the bottom. They should pinpoint the issue for you without trouble. If they help you, please post an additional answer below. I am curious as to what causes this failure for you.

Comment: Thank you. I did this but even the people from Heroku don't know an answer.. Seems like bundler isn't installed on heroku. This is the feedback i've got from cloud9 support..